# Haskell expression for function mutating its surrounding environment?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Haskell is a pure functional language, that provides syntax sugar for the equivalent of imperative expressions. For example, this Python code:

```
def f():
    n = 0
    for i in range(10):
        n += 1
    return n
```

can be translated line by line into isomorphic Haskell code using monads.

Is the same true of code where a function mutates its surrounding environment? For example:

```
def f():
    n = 0
    def g():
        nonlocal n
        n += 1
    for i in range(10):
        g()
    return n
```

Is there a way to translate the above line by line into isomorphic Haskell?

I'm perfectly prepared for the answer to be no, the code needs to be redesigned to do the same thing in a different way. But I figure it's worth asking if there is an isomorphic translation.

Comment: You can work with a `State` monad.

Comment: Can you show us the isomorphic translation of the first snippet please? It then should become clearer why you think that a function call that does mutations could not be translated in the same way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can work with a [**`State`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#t:State) to encapsulate changes of `State`.

In that case your `g` can thus look like:

```
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy(State, modify)

g :: State Int ()
g = modify (1+)
```

then `f` is also a `State` that will first set the state to `0` and then run `g` ten times:

```
import Control.Monad(replicateM_)
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy(State, get, put)

f :: State Int Int
f = do
    put 0
    replicateM_ 10 g
    get
```

You can then run `f` with [**`evalState :: State s a -> s -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#v:evalState) where we provide an initial state and it will return the result of the `State s a` item, so here the what the `get` returns:

```
Prelude Control.Monad.State.Lazy> evalState f 0
10
```

Comment: I was preparing to use `forM_ [1..10]` because it's slightly more similar to the Python in that `[1..10]` matches `range(10)`, but `replicateM_ 10` is undoubtedly superior.

Comment: Hm, with `State` the notion of scope doesn't seem to translate as easily. With only a single variable `n` it's simple, but what if you incremented two different variables in that loop? How to represent the closure of `g` over `n`? I think this needs a `STRef` or something similar.

Comment: @Bergi Indeed. I can see the following options to model multiple variables: 1) `State (Int, String, .....)` and suitable updates for the right component, 2) the same, but with records, 3) `STRef`s, 4) `IORef`s. One might need `ContT` on top if non-local returns are needed (`break`, `raise Exception`, `longjmp`). For complex algorithms, `STRef`s seem good enough, unless IO is needed.

Comment: In the OP `n` is a local variable in `f`. There's no nonlocal state affecting what `f` returns. So a closer translation would use `evalState` internally and get rid of `State` from `f`'s type. That also avoids the slight weirdness of having to pass an extra `0` to "call" `f`, even though it's doing `put 0` first thing itself. To me, an initial assignment in Python *creating* a new variable corresponds more to an `evalState` call initialising some state than it does to a `put` call (which necessarily overwrites state that already exists).

Answer (score 3):

William Van Onsem mentioned the `State` monad in the comment, which works.  You could also refactor this into a tail-recursive function. For example:

```
module Test (f) where

f :: Int
f = go 0 10 where
  go :: Int -> Int -> Int
  go n 0 = n
  go n i = go (g n) (i-1)
  g n = n+1
```

This captures the state by making it an argument to the function.  It optimizes reasonably well, too.  On GHC 8.6.2 with `-O3`, the relevant part of this compiles to:

```
.Lc2gN:
        testq %rsi,%rsi
        jne .Lc2gS
        movq %r14,%rbx
        jmp *(%rbp)
.Lc2gS:
        decq %rsi
        incq %r14
        jmp .Lc2gN
```

You can see that Haskell passes a continuation to which the branch for the terminating case jumps, similar to but not quite the same as how a traditional imperative language pushes a return address onto the stack.  Otherwise, this generated code is precisely equivalent to a `while` or `for` loop in an imperative language: there’s a test of the termination condition, a body that updates the registers holding the sum and counter, and a jump back to the top of the code block.

This approach works well for many loops in imperative programs, although not all.  If the loop has visible side-effects or mutates a large data structure in place, you will need a different solution, such as combining the `State` monad with `IO` using `StateT`.

Comment: I think you accidentally left out the recursive call. This will produce an error as written: `Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t3 ~ t2 -> t3`.